# Show textual representation of f.select options instead of using the values rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in a form:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
  <%= f.label :from_age, "From Age" %><br>
  <%= f.select :from_age, [*-1..65], {}, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
  <%= f.label :to_age, "To Age" %><br>
  <%= f.select :to_age, [*-1..65] << 1000, {}, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

In other words:

For `from_age`, the user selects an age between the numbers -1 through 65.  -1 represents the concept of "All".

For `to_age`, the user selects an age between the numbers -1 through 65, and also can choose the number 1000.  -1 represents the concept of "All", and 1000 represents the concept of "and up".

With the `from_age` and `to_age` specified, The app can now say:

- An agency serves individuals of `All` Ages
- An agency serves individuals of ages `18 and up`
- An agency services individuals of ages `25-40`

When creating a new agency, the above code works ok, but the user needs to know that the value `-1` stands for `up`, and the value `1000` stands for the value `and up`.

I can do better.  I just need to have text that represents the values within the select box,  So within the select box: instead of seeing `-1` the user sees: `All`, and instead of `1000` the user sees: `and up`.

I do have the following in my `Agency` model:

```
def from_age_to_s
  if from_age == -1
    return "All"
  else
    return from_age
  end
end

def to_age_to_s
  case to_age
  when  -1
    "All"
  when 1000
    "+up"
  else
    to_age
  end
end
```

So basically I need to tell the form: "Yes, those are the values and are correct, but for the displayed text for those values, utilize these methods for the text that represents those values that get passed through the form.

[Documentation on select form helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).

Perhaps in this situation it is better to use [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)?

**Update**:

Thanks to the help provided by the answer below.  Here is my solution for `from_age`:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
  <%= f.label :from_age, "From Age" %><br>
  <%= f.select :from_age, options_for_from_date, {}, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

# helpers/application_helper.rb 
def options_for_agencies_from_date
  [ [ 'All', -1 ], *0..65]
end

def options_for_agencies_to_date
  [ [ 'All', -1 ], *0..65, [ '+up', 1000 ] ]
end
```

Comment: Don't do `[*-1..65]`. A Range object responds to `map`; you don't need to convert into it an Array first. Just do `(-1..65).map`. (And in the event you want to convert a Range to an Array, just use `.to_a`, i.e. `(-1..65).to_a`).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a slight improvement: You don't need to do the `[ num, num ]` thing.

Comment: @Jordan super slick!  I updated my update in the question.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array like `[ [ 'Label 1', 'value 1' ], [ 'Label 2', 'value 2'  ], ... ]` to `select`, which will result in options like these:

```html
<option value="value 1">Label 1</option>
<option value="value 2">Label 2</option>
...
```

But there's also a shortcut we can use: Not every element in the choices array has to be a `[ label, value ]` array like above. For elements that aren't arrays, `select` will just use the value for both the label and the value. In other words, if we do this:

```ruby
choices = [ [ 'Foo', 1 ], 2, 3, [ 'Bar', 4 ] ]
```

...then `select` will render options like this:

```html
<option value="1">Foo</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">Bar</option>
```

Armed with this knowledge, we can generate an array with the labels and values we want (you'll probably want to make it a constant at the top of your controller so it's only calculated once):

```ruby
class MyController < ApplicationController
  AGE_CHOICES = [ [ 'All', -1 ], *0..65, [ '+up', 1000 ] ]

  # ...
end

puts MyController::AGE_CHOICES
# => [ [ 'All',   -1 ],
#      0,
#      1,
#      ...
#      65,
#      [ '+up', 1000 ] ]
```

Now in your view you can just do this:

```eruby
<%= f.select :from_age, MyController::AGE_CHOICES, {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

...which will render something like this:

```html
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
...
<option value="1000">+up</option>
```